# define table name in laravel model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent, localization

when I define  table name in laravel model like

```
class Test extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;
        protected $table="en_test";
```

and write in my code

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
Test::get();
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

I have under result

```
"query" => "select * from `en_test` where `en_test`.`deleted_at` is null"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.88
```

But when I set table name like 
protected $table;

```
class Test extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public function __construct()
       {
           $locale =\App::getLocale();
           $this->table=$locale."_test";
       }
```

and write previous code. I have

```
"query" => "select * from `en_test`"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.93
```

Why `where`fa_test`.`deleted_at`is null`  deleted from my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use custom code in your constructor and you haven't launched parent constructor here, so traits were not booted. You should use:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $locale =\App::getLocale();
   $this->table=$locale."_test";
   parent::_construct();
}
```

to launch parent constructor.